# create-project in root directory without the project's directory

Tags: php, composer-php

Say you have this file structure:

```
/myapp/
/myapp/composer.phar
```

If you run `create-project` in the root of `/myapp/` e.g., `php composer.phar create-project foo/bar`

This will create files like this:

```
/myapp/
/myapp/bar/x.txt
/myapp/bar/y.txt
/myapp/composer.phar
```

Is it possible to omit the `bar` directory so that it will look like this?

```
/myapp/
/myapp/x.txt
/myapp/y.txt
/myapp/composer.phar
```

I understand that I could simply move up one directory before running the command, however I am using Vagrant/Docker and it will be simpler if the above is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As they say "When everything else fail, RTFM" :), so:

```
$ composer create-project --help
```

and you see that we got something interested here:

```
Usage:
create-project [options] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]
```

Arguments are optional (which you exercise) but not useless therefore for all non explicitly provided arguments, Composer will provide the value on its own. This also includes `<directory>` which will be then "derived" from `<package>` name. To solve your problem you just need to tell Composer what directory your want it to use, and if that's should be your current working directory, simply pass `.` (dot), which in U*ix world means "current directory":

```
$ composer create-project some/package .
```

and you should be good.

Comment: I actually tried this first, but it errors to "Project directory is not empty.". I guess because it contains `composer.phar`

Comment: Yes, that's the reason - Composer rejects using non-empty dirs to avoid files overwrite etc. Anyway, this can be easily solved by moving *.phar to i.e. /tmp or parent dir as location of the composer is irrelevant for the whole process.